# Trying to code Twitter Bot Getting "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'FILE_NAME'"

Tags: python, twitter

I am currently trying to code a twitter bot (using a YT tutorial) and my code is practically identical with the instructor but I am getting this error

"FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'FILE_NAME'"

The file last_seen.txt is in the same folder as the app.py folder is in.

Here is the code:

```
import tweepy

consumer_key = 'plQA5TXXXXXXX3bmnv7'
consumer_secret = 'PqXXXXXXXm02hNt'
key = '1131XXXXXXmdkDbVt'
secret = 'aPlZNXXXXXXT7b3CWjksG'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(key, secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

FILE_NAME = 'last_seen.txt'

def read_last_seen(FILE_NAME):
    file_read = open("FILE_NAME", 'r')
    last_seen_id = int(file_read.read().strip())
    file_read.close()
    return last_seen_id

def store_last_seen(FILE_NAME, last_seen_id):
    file_write = open(FILE_NAME, 'w')
    file_write.write(str(last_seen_id))
    file_write.close()
    return

tweets = api.mentions_timeline(read_last_seen(FILE_NAME), tweet_mode='extended')

for tweet in reversed(tweets):
    if 'ultimatebadewanne' in tweet.full_text.lower():
        print(str(tweet.id) + ' - ' + tweet.full_text
```

And here is the terminal's output

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.8 /Users/hg/Documents/HGAgencyBot/bot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hg/Documents/HGAgencyBot/bot.py", line 26, in <module>
    tweets = api.mentions_timeline(read_last_seen(FILE_NAME), tweet_mode='extended')
  File "/Users/hg/Documents/HGAgencyBot/bot.py", line 15, in read_last_seen
    file_read = open("FILE_NAME", 'r')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'FILE_NAME'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I would really appreciate if anybody could help me fix this!

Comment: You should use: file_read = open(FILE_NAME, 'r') instead of file_read = open("FILE_NAME", 'r')

Comment: I edited your post to mask your keys and secrets, you should go to the Twitter Developer dashboard and re-generate them to avoid people misusing them.

Answer (score 2):

you are trying to work with file which is named "FILE_NAME" , instead you need to refer to variable called FILE_NAME.
change this

```
def read_last_seen(FILE_NAME):
    file_read = open("FILE_NAME", 'r')
    last_seen_id = int(file_read.read().strip())
    file_read.close()
    return last_seen_id
```

to this

```
def read_last_seen(FILE_NAME):
    file_read = open(FILE_NAME, 'r')
    last_seen_id = int(file_read.read().strip())
    file_read.close()
    return last_seen_id
```